# Google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having the following problem: When I compile my project in Log cat is giving the following error message:

E/AndroidRuntime(555): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
01-14 19:19:49.426: E/AndroidRuntime(555): at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: follow this link:https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java.lang.noclassdeffounderror%3a%20com.google.android.gms.r%24styleable%20in%20android

Answer (score 0):

Import the google play services module into your project from the android sdk.

This is found under /extras/google_play_services/libproject

Then you will have access to all the resources in google play including gms entries.